# Are Rileys Fading Away?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> My prefix is pretty clever and funny
>   My infix can sit, though not on his ass,
>   My suffix is owned by someone,
>   though not by me, by a bonny lass.

**What am I?**

Comment: *'Tis inevitable that some day, Riley Riddles will fade away...*

Comment: probably,but not anytime soon though :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using @Cashbee's Prefix, are you:

> Withers

Prefix:

> WIT

Infix:

> From @Cashbee: 'IT' people have desk jobs so they can sit all day, but not on their ass - as in they always have plenty of work to do.

Suffix:

> HERS (owned by a girl = it's hers)

Title:

> When something withers, it fades away.

Comment: you are very nearly there, just need to finish up now.

Comment: I was about to post exactly the same answer. I too have no idea what the infix is about

Comment: my best guess for infix is rot13('GU' fgnaqf sbe gnoyr urnqre (UGZY), juvpu *fvgf* nobir n gnoyr.) I doubt this is it though..

Comment: Worth a try, have edited it in

Comment: an unusual but interesting guess for the infix, but not the intended one.

Comment: another infix idea: rot13('VG' crbcyr unir qrfx wbof fb gurl pna fvg nyy qnl, ohg abg ba gurve nff - nf va gurl nyjnlf unir cyragl bs jbex gb qb.)

Comment: got the infix this time but the explanation is more based on wordplay.

Comment: @AHKieran update the infix as found by cashbee in his latest comment, also include the title hint found by simone, and i will accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Whitney Houston?

My prefix is pretty clever and funny

> WIT

My infix can sit, though not on his ass,

> KNEE (can kneel, which is some sort of sitting)

My suffix is owned by someone,

> YOU

though not by me, by a bonny lass.

> ?

Together:

> Wit-knee you-?????  is homophone with the start of the name of Whitney Houston, a bonny lass.

Comment: an interesting answer, but not yet correct, you got a partial correct though. $+1$ for you

Answer (score 2):

This is my guess, inspired by @Cashbee's prefix.

Are you

> withering?

Prefix

> WIT

Infix

> HER (because she can sit, but not on *his* ass. Though, "she" would fit better :( )

Suffix

> RING (since rings are *typically* a female accessory. Or maybe, you in particular don't own a ring, while definitely some "bonny lass" does)

Are Rileys Fading Away?

> = Are Rileys Withering?